# Merge/Inline Structs

Tags: c

```
typedef struct { int a : 1; } STRA;
typedef struct { STRA stra; int b : 1; } STRB;
```

Size of STRA is 4 bytes, and size of STRB is 8 bytes.

```
typedef struct { int a : 1; } STRA;
typedef struct { int a : 1; int b : 1; } STRB;
```

Size of STRA is 4 bytes, and size of STRB is 4 bytes.

Can I make STRB 4 bytes while still using STRA inside it?

Comment: Nope, sorry, that's not how C structs work - composing them never allows you to "inline" one struct into another. A macro defining the fields you want might be a better choice.

Comment: Yes you can. Use union, or some kind of `pragma`'s supported by your compiler.

Comment: @yvw `union` is not right, that will overlap them.

Comment: @Barmar and? maybe that is the intention.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. He wants it to be equivalent to the last `typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  When `STRB` contains a member of type `STRA`, that member has to be usable as its own object.  So even if `STRA` contains padding that would be large enough to contain some more members of `STRB`, it can't be used in that way.  Those other members will have to use space that doesn't overlap the `STRA` member.

To see why, consider code like the following:

```
void update(STRA *p) {
    static STRA new = { 1 };
    *p = new;
}

STRB sb;

void foo(void) {
    sb.b = 1;
    update(&sb.stra);
    printf("%d\n", sb.b);
}
```

The assignment in `update` will typically be done by copying all 4 bytes of `new`, including the padding, into `*p`.  If some of that space is used for `sb.b`, it would be overwritten, and `foo()` would not output `1` as expected.

I guess you could have an implementation where assignment of a struct copied the fields one by one, leaving the padding alone; but this would be a lot less efficient, and would be a waste of time for the normal situation where the padding really doesn't contain anything of interest.

This also shows why it's not possible to go the other way and store `sb.stra` in the padding of `STRB`; the object `sb.stra` needs to have its own address in order for this code to work, and it needs to be a full 4 bytes in size, so that functions like `update()` can safely write all 4 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

This seem to work for `gcc`. My eyes are not used to bit fiddling. You should decide if the code answers your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct a {
    int v : 1;
}a;

#pragma pack(pop)

typedef struct b {
    a   a_value;
    int b_value : 1;
}b;


int main()
{
    b variable;
 
    printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b), sizeof(variable.a_value));

    variable.a_value.v = ~0;
    variable.b_value   = ~0;

    printf("0x%04x\n", *(unsigned*)&variable);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :
`1 4 1`
`0x0101`

Comment: This is not the correct output; if the fields were really next to each other (as in the second `STRB` in the question), the output should be 0x0003 (two LSBs set). It looks like GCC has decided that `sizeof(a) = 1` despite the `int` specifier, thereby packing the `a_value` and `b_value` into adjacent bytes - but not adjacent bits, as `int a : 1; int b : 1;` would do.

Comment: @nneonneo the OP did not asked to pack two structs at a bit boundary. The question is pretty clear to me. Please read it again. And the output **is** correct. The code were compiled and run.

Comment: OP writes `typedef struct { int a : 1; int b : 1; } STRB;` as the second example. This contains two adjacent bitfields (i.e. two fields packed into adjacent bits of the same byte).

Comment: @nneonneo Add `#pragma`'s to pack second struct to three bytes, now the first struct will be one byte. So the struct `STRB` will be four bytes and he can still use struct `STRA` in it. As requested by OP. Again, please read the question.